# Discord.js: Как я могу сделать так, чтобы бот посылал сообщение при входе на сервер?

Tags: javascript, discord

Я пробовал сделать это с помощью триггера, который проверял бы, кто входил на сервер: клиент бота или случайный юзер.

```
client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
  if(member.id == client.user.id){
    member.guild.channels.first().send("Worked!")
  }
  else{
    if(db.get(`guild${member.guild.id}.welcome_switch`)==true){
      member.guild.channels.first().send(`<@${member.id}> welcome!`)
    }
    else{
      pass()
    }
  }
});
```

Если что, я отдельно сделал функцию pass(), которая ничего не делает и использовал датабазу quick.db, чтобы хранить в ней значение, которое отвечает за приветствие.
Однако это не принесло плодов. Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Answer (score 1):

В общем, я нашел ответ на свой собственный вопрос:

```js
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
    const channels = guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == "text");

    channels.first().send("Worked!").catch(e => console.log(e));
});
```

Спасибо англоязычной версии stackoverflow за [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63309007/14951146)